# How does print handle the comma exactly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, python-internals

Originally I thought:

```
print "text",
```

would be pretty much the same as

```
sys.stdout.write("text" + " ")
```

but then I tried following:

```
print '(',
sys.stdout.write("text")
print ')'
```

expected output:

```
( text)
```

or

```
(text )  # if the space is added by the next print statement
```

what I got:

```
(text)  # no space at all
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? I'm just curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing consists of converting items to strings, then writing them to a file object (which is `sys.stdout` by default). In Python 2, the `print` statement keeps a flag on the file object you write to, called the *soft space flag*. See the [`file.softspace` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.softspace) and the [`PyFile_SoftSpace()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/file.html#c.PyFile_SoftSpace) in the Python C API.

This flag is used to track when to write a space. Printing is internally implemented as a series of [`PRINT_` opcodes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-PRINT_EXPR), and those manage the flag:

- printing an item (with `PRINT_ITEM` or `PRINT_ITEM_TO`) first checks the flag and will write a space if it is set, and after writing the item out will set the flag again
- writing a newline is a separate opcode (`PRINT_NEWLINE` or `PRINT_NEWLINE_TO`), and the clears the flag without writing a space.

However, writing to the file object *directly*, as you did with `sys.stdout.write()`, clears that flag (before executing the write):

```
>>> import sys
>>> if True:
...     sys.stdout.softspace = 1
...     sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(sys.stdout.softspace))
...     sys.stdout.softspace
...
1
0
```

(I used an `if` block to prevent the interpreter loop from writing the prompt in between).

So this is what happens in your example:

- `(` is written to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stdout.softspace` is set.
- `sys.stdout.write('text')` *clears* the flag again and writes out `text`
- before writing `)`, `PRINT_ITEM` checks for the flag, finds it is not set, and writes `)`. The flag is set again.
- A newline is written by `PRINT_NEWLINE`, clearing the flag again.

All this is a lot of work to keep track of a simple feature, and one of the reasons that Python 3 moved to a *function* for printing. See [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/).

Comment: I also tried in the console and I used `if True:` to exeucte all commands at once ;) thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: @Aemyl: I've just gone ahead and stole the `if True` idea there ;-)